# text-align end is not placing my button to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a window bar in my dialog page where there is a color back ground, a text on the left side and an button on the right side which will allow user to click on it to close the dialog window. For some reason i cant get the button to display on the right. I tried the text-align right or end but for some reason it does not work. Not sure what i am missing here

[image]

```css
.ds-primary-bg {
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.xbutton {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0ch;
  text-align: end;
}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ds-primary-bg">
  <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
  <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
</div>
```

I also included codepen which has the example

https://codepen.io/NoSoup4You2/pen/ZEavYeY

Comment: Do You want to add Your button to the right end inside the blue bar or outside the blue bar?

Comment: text-align wil not self-align but the content. The buttons content is just the "x" not the button itself. give it a `margin-left: auto;`

Comment: I gave answer there ... as code snippet attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using

```
`  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;`
```

inside your `.ds-primary-` class. Please Apply the Code below and you're good to go.
HTML:

```
`<div class="ds-primary-bg">
  <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
  <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
  .ds-primary-bg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.xbutton {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0ch;
  text-align: end;
}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

[Here is the codePen link](https://codepen.io/rafia_zafar/pen/YzEYPJL)

Answer (score 1):

align item can be done with many ways in CSS

- using flexbox
- make button display block and set margin-left

**1st option using flexbox**

```css
.ds-primary-bg {
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.flex-button{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}
.xbutton {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0ch;

}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ds-primary-bg">
  <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
  <div class="flex-button">
  <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

**2nd option make the button display as block and send right side**

> Displays an element as a block element (like button). It starts on a
> new line and takes up the whole width

```css
.ds-primary-bg {
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.xbutton {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0ch;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ds-primary-bg">
  <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
  <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample but in both of your samples the X ended up outside the blue bar which i did not want

Answer (score 0):

It's Not an a text that's why it is not working as you are trying to align it.

```css
.ds-primary-bg {
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.xbutton {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0ch;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ds-primary-bg">
  <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
  <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything in a website an object. Either an element-object or a node-object. Button same as a text is an element. `text-align` does not align texts it align inline-elements. Text same as a button is an inline-element and can be aligned with `text-align`

Comment: Sorry and thanks at the same time. I was trying to answer in a physics perspective as particle object and rigid body dynamics thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

As a button inline element, it occupies its content width. If you wrap the button with container(div) then it occupies full width then you can move that button to the right side.

Updated code:

```css
.ds-primary-bg {
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.xbutton {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0ch;
 
}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.button-container{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ds-primary-bg">
  <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
  <div class="button-container">
  <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using this method.
Changes to html, simply move button before the text.

```
<div class="ds-primary-bg">
    <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
    <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
</div>
```

and changes to css

```
.xbutton {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #09f;
   border: 0ch;
   padding-top: 2%;
   text-align: end;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change position button everywhere that you want base parent.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
}
.ds-primary-bg {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #09f;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.text-white {
  color: white;
}
.xbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0;
}

.tooltext {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="ds-primary-bg">
      <h3 class="tooltext">Menu Item Edit</h3>
      <button type="button" class="xbutton text-white">X</button>
    </div>
```